# Resque Not Picking Up Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, webrick

So, I am trying to set up resque and it is a bit of a weird issue. I had it working before, but I don't know what happened.

When I run the command:

```
QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

It starts webrick and the following output is given:

[2013-04-05 12:41:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=55507 port=2010

However, after a while, it is stuck there and never picks up a job. If I ctrl-c to end it, I get the output:

[2013-04-05 12:43:22] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2013-04-05 12:43:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.

And it begins to start picking up jobs. Clearly something is stuck, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The QUEUE='*' should be in quotation marks (double or single).